# Data format being changed when saving .xls file with Python

Tags: javascript, python

TLDR I have dates that show in this format '44992', which I can't recognise - is there a way to turn that into another format in JS?

I have a Python script that pulls a spreadsheet from a website. In that original spreadsheet, there's a column with dates in this format: `07/03/2023 00:00:00`

There's an issue with the spreadsheet that two columns have the same name, so I run a function which opens the spreadsheet, changes the name of one of those columns, and then re-saves it. After that, the date is in this format: `44992`

I don't understand why it's doing that or what format the second number correlates to - but is there a way to turn that number back into mm/dd/yyyy? Or any other format really! I'm handling the data on the front-end with Javascript, and need to be able to show the date.

This is the function that fixes the name of the column:

```
def fix():
    rb = xlrd.open_workbook('static/files/sheet.xls')
    wb = copy(rb)

    # open the first sheet
    w_sheet = wb.get_sheet(0)

    # row number = 0 , column number = 1
    w_sheet.write(1, 20, 'Applicant postcode')
    w_sheet.write(1, 4, 'Postcode')

    # save the file
    wb.save('static/files/fixed.xls')

    return "File has been fixed"
```

I've tried doing `new Date()` on those numbers, but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the number `44992` that you see is an epoch or UNIX time or in Excel, it's a serial number.
In order to save it in the right format you need to store the dates as a string or use libraries that will do it for you and change only what you need.
Or in JS you need to convert from timestamp to Date format.

Comment: I found a JS package called moment that says it does that, but it is still telling me 01/01/1970 (which isn't the date I'm after - should be in 2023). I put the numbers in here too, and it says the same: https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: the difference between the Excel epoch (January 1, 1900) and the Unix epoch (January 1, 1970) is 25569 days and multiplies the number of days by the number of seconds in a day (86400). So if you want to get it via JS then you need to convert it first to UNIX timestamp: `moment.unix((44992 - 25569) * 86400).format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss");`